# WinHTTrack Website Copier for morroring website with login (password protection)

Tags: windows, internet, proxy, web-crawler

I have a login protected site to which I know the login username and password. I need to use WinHTTrack to clone that site.

I came across many tutorials on the internet but none of them are working for me, when I follow the instructions nothing happens, link from browser is never sent to WinHTTrack

They ask to temporarily set proxy address and port but it is not working for me.

Some tutorials I referred:

1. http://httrack.kauler.com/help/CatchURL_tutorial
2. https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-configure-httrack-for-a-website-with-password-protection